# How do I stop bootstraps table background color setting for print media over riding my class setting

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I am using twitter-bootstrap as the main styling for my HTML.

I have a table which is generated (from an ember app) and each cell of the table has a background color set to indicate a certain state. The color is set with a class selector.

This work perfect for the screen, but when printing I just get white background color, because bootstrap defines the following:

```
@media print {
  .table td, .table th {
    background-color: #fff !important;
  }
}
```

My html looks something like this:

```
<table class-"table table-condensed>
   <tr>
     <td class="bg-color1>Content</td>
     <td class="bg-color2>Content</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

My css looks like this:

```
.bg-color1 {
  background-color: #ababab;
}
.bg-color2 {
  background-color: #bababa;
}
@media print {
 .bg-color1 {
   background-color: #ababab;
 }
 .bg-color2 {
   background-color: #bababa;
 }
}
```

It still doesn't work if I use `!important` in the print media class descriptions. Also if I add the following to 'undo' the td th setting from bootstrap it doesn't work as this takes precedence over my class settings so I still don't get the color when printed

```
@media print {
 .table td, .table th {
   background-color: initial !important;
  }
}
```

There seems no way to get colored backgrounds when printing with class selector using bootstrap. Does anyone have a solution for this.

Comment: When referring your external sheets, link your own CSS after Bootstrap's. This way, your CSS takes priority.

Comment: I have just checked the link order for the style sheets and my own is already linked after the bootstrap one.

Comment: might be also the printer set to not print background-color & background-image .... and CSS cannot override user hardware setting :( (for myself, i'm glad this is the defaut printing setup ... spares me ink and time :) )

Comment: Why don't you just comment out the line in bootstrap's css?

Comment: Wait a second...maybe the `initial` value refers to white? How about you try to set it to a different color by hex code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh yeah, just noticed something...
CSS has this pain-in-the-butt preference thing where the larger your selection tree, the more priority it has. See [CSS specifity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) for more information.

For example,
`table > td` takes priority over just `td`

In Bootstrap's CSS, the `td` is selected as `.table td`, but your selector is just `.bg-color1` or `.bg-color2`

There are two ways to fix this.

1. Remove the `!important` from Bootstrap's CSS and keep the `!important` in your CSS
2. Increase the length of your selector, something like `.table .bg-color1`

I have no evidence to prove this, but this is what I've noticed.

Comment: Thank you! Absolutely correct. Number 2 worked perfectly - it was the the length of the selection tree that prevented my style ever being used, but matching the length to the bootstrap selection did it.

Comment: Yay! Also, if anyone can find a documentation for this weird CSS occurrence, please edit my answer to include it...

Answer (score 0):

> IF a user has "Print Background colours and images" turned off in their print settings, no CSS will override that, so always account for that. This is a default setting.Once that is set so it will print background colours and images, what you have there will work.It is found in different spots. In IE9beta it's found in Print->Page Options under Paper options.In FireFox it's in Page Setup -> [Format & Options] Tab under Options.

May Help:

```
body {
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
}
```

Comment: No this doesn't help I'm afraid. I'm testing using chrome debugger, setting emulate css media set to print. If I set a media colour using the selector .table td then my back ground color displays, but trying to set it with a class selector it does not.